# GUI Interface for ACL (Cisco)

Tags: cisco, access-control-list, interface, graphical-user-interface

Are there any interface (GUI) software to manage ACL? Using Cisco ACL, but it's hard to manage with command line. Any ideas?

Basically, need a software tool to manage ACL permissions with GUI instead of command line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does what you need? https://www.manageengine.com/products/oputils/

Not tried it, just Googled for a tool.

https://www.manageengine.com/products/oputils/help/cisco_uitlities/access_list_tool.html

Comment: Yes, this is a great example of what i need. However, I need an open source (free) tool. :(